# how to produce multiple readlength.tsv at once from multiple fastq files?

Tags: bash, loops, fastq, sbatch

ı have 16 fastq files under the different directories to produce `readlength.tsv` seperately and ı have some script to produce `readlength.tsv` .this is the script that ı should use to produce `readlength.tsv`

```
zcat ~/proje/project/name/fıle_fastq | paste - - - - | cut -f1,2 | while read readID sequ;
do
    len=`echo $sequ | wc -m`
    echo -e "$readID\t$len"
done > ~/project/name/fıle1_readlength.tsv
```

one by one ı can produce this readlength but it will take long time .I want to produce readlength at once thats why I created list that involved these fastq fıles but ı couldnt produce any loop to produce `readlength.tsv` at once from 16 fastq files.

ı would appreaciate ıf you can help me

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. But you can try `xargs` to process multiple files from a list. `ls ~/proje/project/name/*fastq | xargs zcat | paste - - - - | cut -f1,2  | while read readID sequ; do  len=`echo $sequ|wc -m`;  echo -e "$readID\t$len"; done`

Comment: hello  ı m sorry not to be clear. I have multiple fastq files under the different diretories and ı was trying to produce  multiple readlength from these fastq files that s why ı created list . one by one ı can produce this readlength but ıt will tae long time ı want to produce at once

Comment: it may help if you could update the question to include 5-10 lines of output from each of `zcat`, `zcat|paste` and `zcat|paste|cut` so that we have a better understanding of what the data looks like at each step; it's possible there are multiple possible answers, some of which may be able to replace, say, the `paste` and `cut` calls as well as the loop, but we'll need to see some actual data; also keep in mind that any degree of parallel operations may be limited by the number of available cpus as well as the io bandwidth of your disk(s)

Comment: tahnk you so much it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a file `list.txt` contains the 16 file paths such as:

```
~/proje/project/name/file1_fastq
~/proje/project/name/file2_fastq
..
~/path/to/the/fastq_file16
```

Then would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r f; do                # "f" is assigned to each fastq filename in "list.txt"
    mapfile -t ary < <(zcat "$f")       # assign "ary" to the array of lines
    echo -e "${ary[0]}\t${#ary[1]}"     # ${ary[0]} is the id and ${#ary[1]} is the length of sequence
done < list.txt > readlength.tsv
```

As the `fastq` file format contains the id in the 1st line and the sequence
in the 2nd line, bash built-in `mapfile` will be better to handle them.

As a side note, the letter `ı` in your code looks like a non-ascii character.

Comment: tahnk you so much it works :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. If you feel my answer
solves well your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by
clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.